# Creating Button Shortcuts with Java like & (ampersand) with Windows Forms

Tags: java, winforms, swing, netbeans, windows-forms-designer

I wish I could word this question better. Partly I just don't know the name of what I'm looking for.

With Visual Studio and Windows forms you can add an ampersand to create a "shortcut" key to a button by pressing Alt + [That Letter]. Like `My &Button` ... Alt + B would be the shortcut.

Is there an equivalent of this in Java SWING? I am using NetBeans IDE 6.9.1.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's called a **[mnemonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonics_%28keyboard%29)**.

Use `setMnemonic` ([javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMnemonic%28int%29))

*See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#mnemonic*

Comment: Awesome, that totally works. Thanks! You can also set this in the NetBeans IDE by setting the letter of the character you want in the `mnemonic` property. It doesn't appear to be case sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

You use `JMenutItem.setMnemonic()`; I don't think there's a handy-dandy shortcut like the ampersand.